# MySQL GROUP BY With Priority To Certain Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that is set up much like this

```
id, eventid, event                           , venue    , performer      , popular, image
 2, 5895   , Garth Brooks and Trisha Yearwood, TD Garden, Trisha Yearwood, n      , empty
 1, 5895   , Garth Brooks and Trisha Yearwood, TD Garden, Garth Brooks   , y      , garth.jpg
```

There is a line for each performer at every event in the database. What I need to do is to `SELECT * FROM events_table WHERE venue = 'TD Garden'` but I need to group them by the event id otherwise multiple lines of the same event will show up.

The problem is that I need to somehow group them with priority to the lines where popular = y. Otherwise Trisha Yearwood could show up and there would be no picture for her. The reason I don't just select everything where popular = y is because some events may not have any popular artists there to begin with and I would need all events at TD Garden not just the popular ones.

Is what I am asking possible with SQL? Sorry if my question is too confusing.

Comment: You can group by arbitrary values, e.g. `group by popular = 'y', other,fields,here`

Comment: Consider providing a more thoroughly representative data set (ideally as a set of DDLs) and a desired result set.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example.  you want garth's image to show for trisha yearwood? or do you want only Garth to be listed since he's popular... What if there's more than one popular?

Comment: @xQbert I would want only Garth to be listed since he is popular. If there are two popular artists it wouldn't really matter which image is shown but the chances of there being two popular artists are slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery selects maximum popularity of each event (`'y'`>`'n'`), so condition `(eventid,popular) in (...)` removes rows for artists what does not have maximum popularity in event where he/she perform.

```
select *
from events_table
where
    venue = 'TD Garden' and
    (eventid,popular) in (
        select
            eventid,
            max(popular)
        from events_table
        group by eventid
    )
group by eventid
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you well, You can select based on all events where it is popular, or has no popular events at all, then do whatever group by you'd like

```
Select [columns here] From 
    (Select [columns here] From events_table ET where venue='your_venue_here' and 
        (popular='y' or not exists
            (Select * From events_table where popular='y' and eventid=ET.eventid)) T
group by eventid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ET.ID, ET.Event_ID, ET.Event, ET.Venue, Coalesce(ET2.Performer, ET.Performer) as Performer Coalesce(ET2.Popular, ET.Popular) as Popular, Coalesce(ET2.Image, ET.Image) as Image
FROM events_table ET
LEFT JOIN Events_table ET2 
 on ET.Event_ID = ET2.Event_ID
 and ET2.Popular='Y'
WHERE venue = 'TD'
```

This may be what you're after but it doesn't handle multiple popular people well.  I also don't know what names you want to display, Just the popular one or should both performer's be listed....